# Upload an image from web page to OneDrive

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I would like to upload selected image from web page, to OneDrive. (without downloading)

API [says](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/javascript-picker-saver.htm) you can save files from your computer using filepicker. But there's no mention about using image from web page.

Is it possible selecting an image from web page and showing as `file` to `form`.

Here's simple save process:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v5.0/OneDrive.js" id="onedrive-js" client-id="000000004816BD7D"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var saverOptions = { file: "file" /* ... */ };
    var saverButton = OneDrive.createSaveButton(saverOptions);
    document.getElementById("save").appendChild(saverButton);
}
</script>

<input id="file" name="file" type="input" />
<div id="save"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, [there's a way](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_url.htm). But I don't want to use oauth. This is a simple job.